# Pyaudio detecting Microphone but not reviving audio

Tags: python, macos, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I've been trying to use speech recognition. I know pyaudio is detecting my microphone, but when I record a wave file through pyaudio, there's no audio in the recording. My mic isn't muted.

Im on mac and working in Visual Studio. Do I need to give microphone permission to VS?

Comment: could you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be that VS doesen't have the permissions for your microphone, because your script is running directly from VS. Try enabling microphone permissions for VisualStudio following those steps:

1. Go to Apple logo > Sistem Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy
2. Search for VisualStudio
3. Check the tickbox next to it.

You can also try to run your script from Python directly.
Hope that this works for you.